# Can MKStoreKit be used for auto-renew in-app purchases? Where in the code do I send up the "shared secret"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, in-app-purchase

Can MKStoreKit be used for auto-renew in-app purchases? Where in the code do I send up the "shared secret"?

Anyone have any experience with using MKStoreKit for auto-renewal in-app subscriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As on date, it doesn't support. I'm planning to implement this feature soon.

Comment: The latest version of MKStoreKit supports this.

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/

Comment: MKStoreKit as of now seems fairly broken wrt auto-renew subscriptions and I would not recommend it for production code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out InventoryKit (IK) - https://github.com/agoodman/inventory-kit

IK supports all in-app purchases, including auto-renewable susbcriptions via a web service called EnrollMint (http://enrollmint.com, [@enrollmint](http://twitter.com/#!/enrollmint)). EnrollMint offers sandbox and production environments for receipt verification, as well as a post-back system to notify your web service of subscription changes. Post-back is critical if you want to also integrate third-party subscription billing providers, like [Chargify](http://chargify.com) or [Recurly](http://recurly.com), to allow users to buy and use subscriptions on the web. EnrollMint acts as the owner of subscription data, coordinating this data between your web and mobile apps, so your users can buy on one device and switch to the web or another device seamlessly.